# Upload de Imagem com CKEditor e enviar para outra página

Tags: php, ckeditor

Estou criando um formulário em PHP onde a pessoa cria um relatório diário de obra onde pode ser adicionado imagens e comentários do dia usando o CKEditor, no final gerando um PDF.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que ao gerar o PDF, ele apresenta o seguinte erro na imagem:

[image: erro]

Comment: ali aparece imagem nao encontrada ou formato desconhecido, ja tentou outro formato?

Comment: Então, no cabeçalho precisa de imagem para inserir também, porém não é com o CKEditor e somente pode ser inserido duas imagens, aí eu já utilizo o método getimage do php nas duas imagens, o problema que não da pra fazer isso no CKEditor por que são se sabe quantas imagens serão inseridas pelo usuário.